# javascript verify 0 as a number

Tags: javascript, input, verification, verify

I am having trouble getting 0 to verify as a selectable "number" in an input field, currently 0 doesn't count to wards the verification.

```
function verifyIt(){
if((Number(document.form1.baseline_du_115.value)) && document.form1.baseline_du_115.value>=0 && document.form1.baseline_du_115.value<=99){
    document.form1.submit();
    return true;
}else{
    alert("How many times per month do you drink more than 3-4 drinks on a single occasion?");
    return false;
}
```

}
I have been told that I'm supposed to make sure that in the if statement, I need to make ==0 a choose-able input. 
I need 0 to not throw the else

Comment: You could really just get rid of the `Number()` part, and just do the comparison. `if (document.form1.baseline_du_115.value>=0 && document.form1.baseline_du_115.value<=99) {` If the value can't be converted, it'll simply return `false`. Though you may want to coerce the value to a number before submitting `document.form1.baseline_du_115.value *= 1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0 == false` evaluates to `true` in javascript, due to the concept of [truthiness](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/). That's why your if clause evaluates to `false` every time.

It appears that you want to verify the `Number(document.form1.baseline_du_115.value)` is defined. Here are some ways you can write that:

```
document.form1.baseline_du_115.value != null
document.form1.baseline_du_115.value !== undefined
!isNaN(Number(document.form1.baseline_du_115.value))
```

Comment: Checking for `null` with `==` also covers `undefined`, so you don't need that second comparison.

Comment: Thanks, I used !isNaN(Number(document.form1.baseline_du_115.value))

Comment: Great! Make sure to mark an answer as "accepted" if you found it is the answer that worked for you :)

Comment: If you use isNaN() Number() is useless

Comment: @Givi that is incorrect. If the argument passed to Number() cannot be evaluated as such, the [return value is NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

Comment: @stinkycheeseman: Although `0 == false` does evaluate to `true`, it's not at all due to the concept of "truthiness". The `==` will never do a *ToBoolean* evaluation of its operands. It uses [a type coercive comparison algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3), which in this case happens to yield the same result, but not in all cases.

Comment: isNaN tries to convert string into Number. Return value true if the value converted to the Number type is the NaN, otherwise false.

Comment: @CrazyTrain While that type coercive comparison algorithm may be what is used, the fact that 0 evaluates to false in an abstract comparison is indeed what people are referring to when they say "truthy" and "falsey" in javascript. 0, null, undefined, NaN, "", and false are all "falsey" values.

Comment: No, it's completely different. Those values will perform a simple *toBoolean* conversion to the `false` value. That's what truthy/falsey means. The algorithm used by `==` will sometimes provide a similar result, and sometimes a different result.

Answer (score 1):

What happens here is that Number(0) translates to 0, which translates to false. If you just want to check that it is a number, replace

```
(Number(document.form1.baseline_du_115.value))
```

with

```
!isNaN((Number(document.form1.baseline_du_115.value)))
```

This works because if you send something that is not a number to `Number()`, you will get NaN

Answer (score 0):

Javascript will translate this to false if the value is 0. Thus making that If statement go Else every time

```
(Number(document.form1.baseline_du_115.value))
```